# %llx format specifier: invalid warning?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

**Edited** to remove the first warning

The following code works as expected in g++ 4.4.0 under mingw32:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
  {
  long long x = 0xdeadbeefc0defaceLL ;
  printf ("%llx\n", x) ;
  }
```

But if I enable all warnings with `-Wall`, it says:

```
f.cpp: In function 'int main()':
f.cpp:5: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
f.cpp:5: warning: too many arguments for format
```

It's the same with `%lld`. Is this fixed in newer versions?

**Edited again to add:**
The warning doesn't go away if I specify `-std=c++0x`, even though (i) `long long` is a standard type, and (ii) `%lld` and `%llx` seem to be officially supported. For instance, from **21.5 Numeric conversions** para 7:

`Each function returns a string object holding the character representation of the value of
its argument that would be generated by calling sprintf(buf, fmt, val) with a format specifier of
"%d", "%u", "%ld", "%lu", "%lld", "%llu", "%f", "%f", or "%Lf", respectively, where buf designates
an internal character buffer of sufficient size.`

So this is a bug, surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long long x = 0xdeadbeefc0defaceLL; // note LL in the end
```

And there is no `ll` length specifier for `printf`. The best you can get is:

```
printf ("%lx\n", x); // l is for long int
```

---

I've tested your sample on my g++, it compiles without errors even without `-std=c++0x` flag:

```
~$ g++ -Wall test.cpp
~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

So, yes, this fixed in newer versions.

Comment: It's tagged C++. The best you can get is `std::cout << std::hex <<  x << '\n';`

Comment: Yes there is no standart specifier for long long type. But `lld` and `llx` are most portables.

Comment: @MSalters: I've added the `c++0x` tag now, to make `long long` a standard type (this was why I tagged it `C++`, but now I realise that `long long` is not standard in `C++` before `C++0x`).

Answer (score 1):

For first warning I can say that you must use `0xdeadbeefc0defaceLL` instead of `0xdeadbeefc0deface`. After that other warnings may pass also.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `LL` now. But the other warnings remain.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same warning compiling C using windows/mingw32.

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
```

So yes, probably a compiler/platform specific bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Mingw-specific issue, because it calls the native Windows runtime for certain things, including this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763854/printf-and-llx-in-gcc-under-windows-64x).

`%I64d` works for me. In the answer linked above there is a more portable albeit less readable solution as well.