# error: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format - scanning long long

Tags: c, scanf, c99

I'm trying to get `long long` from the console using standard IO function `scanf`. I started with `%lld`:

```
scanf("%lld", &rule);
```

That throws:

```
error: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Werror=format=]
```

I've found [more workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400404/607407), but they too throw errors:

```
 scanf("%I64d", &rule);
   ->error: ISO C does not support the 'I64' ms_scanf length modifier [-Werror=format=]
 scanf("%"SCNd64"", &rule);
   ->error: expected ')' before 'SCNd64'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an another trick?

I'm compiling on very recent version of MinGw GCC with these flags: `-pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -g -D HOME=1`

Comment: Try using something like `-std=gnu99` instead of c99.

Comment: If `rule` is `int64_t` instead, try `scanf("%" SCNd64, &rule);` Be sure to include `inttypes.h` and `stdint.h`. [See this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for more info. It should be supported in C99.

Comment: I deleted an answer I had posted; what you are doing complies and executes fine for me with the same gcc options on Linux, so I'm thinking it's something to do with MingW.

Comment: Your implementation is not C99-compliant. Are you sure that `-std=c99` is being passed when the first error message is generated?

Comment: It would be not the first time when the compilation passed very differently on windows and linux.

Comment: `-std=gnu99` yields the same errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf and %llx in GCC under Windows 64x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763854/printf-and-llx-in-gcc-under-windows-64x)

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to add this snippet too:

[MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows / [Mingw-w64-public] -Wformat and %llu](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/20120411101049.GA4263%40glandium.org/#msg29128250)

> the issue is that formatter-width specifier %ll isn't supported for
> all msvcrt-DLL versions, therefore gcc warns about its use.  The
> variant for specifying 64-bit integer-scalar-width in formatter for
> msvcrt in a backward-compatible way is by using %I64.
>
> Use %I64u on Windows, or just use inttypes.h PRIuMAX.
>
> If you must use %llu, define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO macro before
> including stdio.h. Be aware that if you do this, MS type %I64* format
> will no longer work.

Answer (score 6):

for `SCNd64` and similar, you'd have to use

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

but all of this is only supposed to work if your compiler supports C99. Your first error message is a strong indication that it doesn't, or that you didn't give the right commandline switches.

Comment: It doesn't: MinGW re-uses as many software components from Windows as possible, and this includes the C runtime. MinGW's GCC is a chimera of a C99 compiler with a non-C99 standard library.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, after including `inttypes.h`, I'm getting the same errors as before. How can it be possible for a compiler being unable to do such a trivial thing? The command line switches must be kept - the same switches are being used on evaluation server (I'm doing a programming homework).

Comment: As Pascal says, your platform includes components from Windows that aren't C99 compliant. On the evaluation server, if this isn't on a Windows system, you might have more luck.

Comment: Even though we get warning for lld, I observed that correct value is printed (MinGW. In below case, the result printed is 6442450950    
 
unsigned long long var6=2147483650*3;
printf("var6 =%lld\n",var6);

Comment: @rajesh, that's because the libc, not the compiler, does the printing. The libc does the job as the implementation says. The compiler additionally check whether a <standard>-compliant library would correctly handle formatting strings.

Comment: I think these issues/features make C language more bug prone.

Answer (score 0):

Certain compilers, especially Windows-based ones, do not have the lond long data type as a predefined data type. In these cases, what you should do is use the keyword `%" PRId64 "\n"` which is a specification for a high precision long long data type.
To use this function it is necessary to include the #include <inttypes.h> library `#include <inttypes.h>`
In your example it would look like this:

```
scanf("%" SCNd64, &rule);
```